# How to share a DHCP Server(Debian) that is created on VMware to other PC in the same switch

Tags: debian, networking, vmware, dhcp

I've created a dhcp server(in Debian) on VMware.

When I launch a new virtual machine on the same computer it works fine, it receives an IP address from the DHCP server.

But how to connect other virtual machine(that is connected to a second switch port) that is created on other pc?

How to share the DHCP Server(Debian) that is created on VMware to other PCs (that are connected to the switch) on other computers?

Comment: Configure the vmware network as a bridge, it ought to work.